# В Ratchet не получается обратиться к свойству resourceId

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Пытаюсь организовать отправку сообщения конкретному пользователю в WebSocket с использованием Ratchet, как я понял, чтобы это сделать, нужно запомнить соответствие подключения и user_id, но как только я начал пытаться реализовать то, что нагуглил, сразу наткнулся, что я не могу обратиться к свойству переменной $conn, к примеру, если я пишу:

```
$conn->resourceId, $conn->WebSocket, $conn->httpRequest
```

получаю ошибку, что все эти свойства undefined, т.е. я даже ничего не могу попробовать из того, что советуют, поскольку на первой же стадии получаю ошибку, помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю/не понимаю не так?

Comment: проверь $conn. Может он кривой..... нужно больше подробностей, код.... а по этому описанию ничего сказать нельзя, только посоветовать отладку и внимательно читать

Comment: спасибо, я сейчас еще раз перепроверю

Comment: в общем, я перепроверил и понял следующее, что все работает, resourceId и httpRequest определяется, но почему-то vscode ругается - подчеркивает желтеньким и пишет, что есть проблемы и undefined property..